# Can I walk out of Brisbane Airport?

Tags: walking, brisbane

Since I have some time, I may want to walk to my hotel. Walking from Skygate to Novotel should be no problem, since it is in Skygate. The Ibis looks close, but Google maps says that I have to walk along the Great Northern Bikeway to get to the hotel.

https://goo.gl/maps/umnY1seLcNH2

It is hard to tell from Google Maps if there are any "bicycles only" signs on that route, so I can I walk along it? Is there a more direct path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compare the last page of the [Upgrade completition](http://www.bne.com.au/sites/all/files/content/files/Cycling%20and%20ped%20upgrade%20completion_May%202013.pdf) document to your map. It says:

> A new connection between the Domestic and International Terminals
>
> A new connection to help cyclists and pedestrians travel from Qantas Drive to the Domestic Terminal via Airport Drive.
>
> (The orange dotted line shows the upgraded section).

And your map is basically riding the orange dotted line.